# Appending bits in C/C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit

I want to append two unsigned 32bit integers into 1 64 bit integer. I have tried this code, but it fails. However, it works for 16bit integers into 1 32 bit

Code:

```
char buffer[33];
char buffer2[33];
char buffer3[33];

/*
uint16 int1 = 6535;
uint16 int2 = 6532;
uint32 int3;
*/


uint32 int1 = 653545;
uint32 int2 = 562425;
uint64 int3;

int3 = int1;
int3 = (int3 << 32 /*(when I am doing 16 bit integers, this 32 turns into a 16)*/) | int2;


itoa(int1, buffer, 2);
itoa(int2, buffer2, 2);
itoa(int3, buffer3, 2);



 std::cout << buffer << "|" << buffer2 << " = \n" << buffer3 << "\n";
```

Output when the 16bit portion is enabled:

```
1100110000111|1100110000100 =
11001100001110001100110000100
```

Output when the 32bit portion is enabled:

```
10011111100011101001|10001001010011111001 =
10001001010011111001
```

Why is it not working? Thanks

Comment: Would you mind posting the implementation of `_itoa()`?

Comment: There is no language C/C++!

Comment: @EOF _itoa() is a "safer," according to Visual Studio" method of itoa. It claims to be the C/C++ version, hence the tag Olaf

Comment: @DanyilBee, Ah, so it's Microsoft specific. Oh well. Does the function have a prototype you could post?

Comment: @EOF, I'll just change the question to include original POSIX itoa() , if its such a big problem

Comment: @DanyilBee There is no POSIX `itoa()`, only `atoi()`. I'll cut to the chase: I suspect the prototype for microsoft's `_itoa()` is something like `void _itoa(int, char *, int)`, in which case your `uint64_t` is converted, in an implementation-dependent way, to an `int`. In practise, the 64-bit value is probably truncated to 32 bits.

Comment: @EOF Very good assumption, I would have to agree. I tried original itoa()-- still didn't work. itoa was probably written with no idea of 64bit integers, therefore converting them as you said. That would provide a good answer

Comment: For 64-bit unsigned integers, use `_ui64toa`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring buffer3 as buffer3[65]

Edit:
Sorry.
But I don't understand what the complaint is about.
In fact the answer is just as expected. You can infer it from your own result for the 16 bit input.
Since when you are oring the 32 '0' bits in lsb with second integer it will have leading zeroes in msb (when assigned to a 32 bit int which is in the signature of atoi) which are truncated in atoi (only the integer value equivalent will be read in the string, hence the string has to be 0X0 terminated, otherwise it would have a determinable size), giving the result.

Comment: This should really be a comment, not an answer.  While it's a good point that the buffer is too small to hold a 64-bit string, it also appears from the program's output (ignoring the potential undefined behaviour aspect) that `atoi` is actually treating the value as 32-bit and thus _not_ invoking undefined behaviour.  That would relegate your answer to either "just a comment", or "just plain wrong".

Comment: You were right. My first reply was wrong. There is no point using 64 bit buffer because the function deals with 32 bit integers. Instead use the "ltoa" function with a 64 bit buffer.

Answer (score 3):

I see nothing wrong with this code. It works for me. If there's a bug, it's in the code that's not shown.

Version of the given code, using standardized type declarations and iostream manipulations, instead of platform-specific library calls. The bit operations are identical to the example given.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdint.h>    

int main()
{
    uint32_t int1 = 653545;
    uint32_t int2 = 562425;
    uint64_t int3;

    int3 = int1;
    int3 = (int3 << 32) | int2;

    std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(8) << std::setfill('0')
          << int1 << " "
          << std::setw(8) << std::setfill('0')
          << int2 << "="
          << std::setw(16) << std::setfill('0')
          << int3 << std::endl;
    return (0);
}
```

Resulting output:

```
0009f8e9 000894f9=0009f8e9000894f9
```

The bitwise operation looks correct to me. When working with bits, hexadecimal is more convenient. Any bug, if there is one, is in the code that was not shown in the question. As far as "appending bits in C++" goes, what you have in your code appears to be correct.

Comment: Perhaps a problem with itoa? That was one of my thoughts

Comment: It was made quite some time ago, pretty sure when 64 bit was a rarity. Perhaps this is the issue. I will test out your code

Comment: Maybe, but the question is about bitwise manipulations, and this proves that the bitwise manipulations are correct. It's possible that the question here might be "what the heck is this _itoa function is doing", but that would be a different question.

Comment: an objvious problem with the initial code is use of unknown function `itoa`. If it "works for you", a likely explanation would be that you used a different itoa function to OP